# how to initialize constructor arguments by passing JSON at the time of object creation in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

suppose i have a class

```
export class PersonName {
    constructor(
        public firstName: string = "",
        public lastName: string = "",
        public middleName: string = "",
    ) { }
}
```

I want to initialize these variables declared in constructor by passing json object at time of object creation.

for example:

```
var person = new Person({
        "firstName"  : "abc",
        "lastName"   : "xyz",
        "middleName" : ""
       });
```

Comment: Your example is not valid JSON (it's not even valid syntax), Did you mean `:` instead of `=`?

Comment: Yes, It was just a copy paste error. Do you have any solution regarding this?

Answer (score -2):

One way to do it is to provide overloads for the constructor and then test whether the first argument was a string or an object containing the fields:

```
export class Person {
  public firstName;
  constructor(
      firstName: string,
      lastName: string,
      middleName: string,
  );  
  constructor(
      person: { firstName: string, lastName: string, middleName: string }
  );  
    constructor(
        arg1: string | { firstName: string, lastName: string, middleName: string } = "",
        public lastName: string = "",
        public middleName: string = "",
    ) {
      if (typeof arg1 === "string") {
        this.firstName = arg1;
      } else {
        this.firstName = arg1.firstName;
        this.lastName = arg1.lastName;
        this.middleName = arg1.middleName;
      }
    }
}

const person = new Person({
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "middleName": "",
 });
 const person2 = new Person("foo", "bar", "baz");
```